# Partial differential equation with a nowhere differentiable boundary

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, fractals, elliptic-equations

Consider the [Dirichlet boundary value problem of the 2-dimensional Laplace's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation). When the boundary is piecewise smooth, it can be solved by [the Green's function for the double layer potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_layer_potential). Consider the case when the boundary is continuous but nowhere differentiable such as a fractal curve. I would like to know the answers or see a rough survey of the answers, or be pointed to the references pertaining, to the following questions.

1. What is an analog of the Green's function?
2. What are some of the solution methods other than Green's function analog?

Comment: While the question you ask is an interesting one, it is incredibly broad, and leads to a *lot* of interesting mathematics, some of which is still actively being researched.  The actual shape of the domain matters (convex domains, star-convex domains, John domains, &c.), the boundary conditions matter (Dirichlet, von Neuman, Robin, &c.), and the differential operator under consideration matters (obviously?).  Unfortunately, because this question is so broad, I don't think that it is a good fit for MSE, and I have voted to close it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I am aware that this subject in general is broad, that is precisely why I would like to "consider the simple case of the Dirichlet boundary value problem of the Laplace's equation" "with a continuous but nowhere differentiable boundary such as a fractal surface". In any case, I have pared down the question to a completely specific one.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in if there is some Green's function (or at least an analog), or solution methods in general?  The first question seems well-focused to me to me, but the latter -- although also interesting -- probably is too broad.

Comment: @Strants: I would like to know both. Even thought the second question is broad, it does not prevent one from giving some survey and references which are legitimate requests.

Comment: That really isn't much more specific.  The answer depends quite a bit on the exact nature of the domain.  Having a nowhere differentiable boundary is, in some sense, no restriction at all, as *almost every* set (in the sense of Lebesgue) has a nowhere differentiable boundary.  In the case of simply connected domains, I believe that results are known for convex and star-convex domains, and maybe John domains (?), but this is still an area of active research.

Comment: [Johan Thim](http://users.mai.liu.se/johth11/) wrote a fairly well known [Masters thesis on nowhere differentiable continuous functions](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8cfb/8ff14cc7ab6e6010f363355ff5ddf08f11a7.pdf), and it appears that his research is now somewhat close to what you're asking --- *My main area of research is analysis and partial differential equations, in particular on domains with minimal smoothness assumptions.*

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I do not know any of these results. All the solution methods I know are the Green's function (and the related Fourier transform) solution and those stated in e.g. Courant and Hilbert, Methods of Mathematical Physics Volume 2, of say the Laplace equation. They all rely on the piecewise smoothness of the boundary. I would like to enquire about the known solution methods when this smoothness condition is violated. I have edited the question to make it inclining towards survey/reference request. I have added the tag *reference-request* before you posted your comment.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thank you for the reference. It is indeed a good survey paper. However, his master thesis surveys the nowhere differentiable $R\to R$  function, and it does not solve the Laplace equation in the plane.

Comment: If you look again at what I wrote, I only brought up his Masters thesis because I would assume you've heard of it (it's hard to miss it when googling anything about nowhere differentiable continuous functions), and also to point out that his current research on differential equations on domains with little or no differentiability assumptions (what you're asking about) seems to be a natural outgrowth of his earlier interest. I gave a link to his homepage, where I thought the connection to your question would be fairly obvious. (Note: I know almost nothing about DE's and non-smooth boundaries.)

Comment: As I said in another comment, I know almost nothing about this topic, but perhaps these two papers could help: [The boundary-value problems for Laplace equation and domains with nonsmooth boundary](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107642/ArchMathRetro_034-1998-1_16.pdf) by Dagmar Medková (1998) and [Fractal drum, inverse spectral problems for elliptic operators and a partial resolution of the Weyl-Berry conjecture](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1991-325-02/S0002-9947-1991-0994168-5/S0002-9947-1991-0994168-5.pdf) by Michel L. Lapidus (1991).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Ah, I understand now. I took the "my" in "My main area of research..." as your (Dave L. Renfro's). Johan Thim's research area is indeed relevant. Just saw your latest comment. The Weyl-Berry conjecture is actually what I am ultimately after. Thank you for the pointer and the wonderful references.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87860/discussion-between-hans-and-dave-l-renfro).

Comment: OK, I didn't notice the ambiguity with "my". As I said, I don't know anything about this stuff, but I have seen references to Lapidus's paper many times over the years (due to my interest in nowhere differentiability, fractals, and the like). Possible search words might John domain, corkscrew domain, uniform domain, non'tangentially accessible domain, Lipschitz domain, plump domain, cigar domain, ball accessible domain, uniformly perfect domain, etc. An old but probably useful paper is [*Uniform domains*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178228081) by Jussi Väisälä (1988)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I would like to petition you to click the *reopen* button at the bottom of my question. The question in the present form, especially with the reference-request tag, cannot be more specific than it already is, given the nature of the problem itself. Would you agree?

Comment: @Hans: Given what I know about this, I'm not sure I would be able to ask anything more specific, other than I'm not sure whether I'd mention "Green's function" (since for all I know that's a specific technique that might be entirely inappropriate for the situation you're asking about), so I'll do this.